# Why is "Just Some Lines To Me" closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

[Just Some Lines To Me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/116497/just-some-lines-to-me)

It says, the question does not appear to be about creation and solving of puzzles.

**How? Why?**

Answer (score 3):

That's what the post notice says when a custom close reason is used. In this question's case, that reason was:

> Having seen a pretty-much complete answer I'm voting to close, as this is a multi-stage puzzle that relies on external links for the follow-on stages.

The idea is that if a custom explanation is given via comment(s), you could read the discussion in the comment section to understand why the question is off-topic